# Check first 5 rows of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a `gridview` displaying large number of rows from `sql` table. I also have `checkbox` `chkboxSelectAll` in `gridview` header to check all the rows in `gridview`.

Code for `chkboxSelectAll` `oncheckedchange`:

```
protected void chkboxSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox ChkBoxHeader = (CheckBox)Grid.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkboxSelectAll");
            foreach (GridViewRow row in Grid.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkrow");
                if (ChkBoxHeader.Checked == true)
                {
                    ChkBoxRows.Checked = true;
                }
                if (ChkBoxHeader.Checked == false)
                {
                    ChkBoxRows.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

But, I only want to check first 5 rows of gridview after checking header checkbox.

All answers I searched were for datatables or datasets but no one for gridview itself.

Is there any way to do this. Any help will be appreciated..!!

Comment: You an integer. eg `int i = 0; i++; if (i > 5)... `

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have the code to select all and want to change it to just 5 first row. Is this true?

Comment: yes @ConductedClever

Comment: @Jeremy can you explain more how to use it. thanks

Comment: Why down vote??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the answer of the second comment is true, then this will be your solution (for example):

```
    protected void chkboxSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox ChkBoxHeader = (CheckBox)Grid.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkboxSelectAll");
        bool sign = ChkBoxHeader.Checked == true;
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in Grid.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkrow");
            ChkBoxRows.Checked = sign;
            counter++;
            if (counter == 5)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to do that:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in Grid.Rows.Take(5))
{
    CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkrow");
    if (ChkBoxHeader.Checked == true)
    {
        ChkBoxRows.Checked = true;
    }
    if (ChkBoxHeader.Checked == false)
    {
        ChkBoxRows.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @senz but am not using LINQ